# angular2 prevent routing from removing the hash

Tags: hash, routes, angular

I'm using Angular2 and receive data in the hash of a callback. The Angular2 routing removes this before loading the component.

Is there anyway I can **prevent** Angular2 routing from removing the hash from the URL so that I can use this data?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue for that https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595

Comment: And when will this fix be implemented, can't use my server data until this is fixed.

Comment: How should I know? You  already mentioned in the issue it's urgent for you. Google doesn't provide timelines when things will be implemented.

Comment: That's why I asked the question here, to find out, if any other solution is possible, Thanks

Comment: I guess you should update your question to make it clear you're looking for a workaround until the issue is fixed.